# iOS 11 NavigationBar Custom Back button issue

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar, back-button, navigationbar

In my previous app now I want to Update with iOS 11 functionality. So Now I when use below code

```
NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton(false, false);

var negativeSpacae = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FixedSpace);

UIButton button = new UIButton(new RectangleF(0, 0, 30, 30));
button.SetImage(UIImage.FromFile("backbutton"), UIControlState.Normal);
button.TintColor = UIColor.White;
button.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;

var widthconstraint = button.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(27);
var heightconstraint = button.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(20);

widthconstraint.Active = true;
heightconstraint.Active = true;

UIBarButtonItem[] bArray = {
                negativeSpacae, new UIBarButtonItem (button)
                };
NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItems(bArray, true);

button.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
{
   this.NavigationController.PopViewController(true);
};
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
{
   ViewRespectsSystemMinimumLayoutMargins = false;
   View.LayoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;
}
```

It display below output :

[image]

In this output the button image is stretch and it display more right size.

What i am expecting is my button image is left side without stretching.

Any help will be Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> In this output the button image is stretch and it display more right size.

**Cause**: The image size(width * height) is great than the button size. You can check the image file in your application folder, it should be large than 27*20.

**Solution**: `button.ImageView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;`